# How to update array in object in an array with index in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am developing an application using MongoDB and express.

the application is similar to any social media app, the user can create posts and the other users can like the post and also comment on it.

I want to add a feature where a user can like the comment and I've tried a lot and searched too but with no good results.

the json format of a post object:

```
{
  ...,
  comments: [
    {
       title: 'I am a comment in the post !',
       likers: [
          ObjectId('foo'),
          ObjectId('bar'),
       ],
    },
  ],
}
```

I want to either be able to push to likers or pull from with index.

I have tried to update using the following code but I failed since it cant read the commentIndex property and gives error in syntax.

```js
Post.findByIdAndUpdate(postId , { '$push': { 'comments.${commentIndex}.likedUsersIds': mongoose.Types.ObjectId(liker) } })
```

also tried with operator $ and not worked too.

please help me.

Thanks,